# Verify that a PDE is satisfied by a matrix consisting of functions satisfying a different PDE

Tags: differential-equations, calculus-and-analysis, matrix, symbolic

My problem is as follows: I have two matrices $P$ and $Q$ which are made up of algebraic expressions of a function $q(x,t)$ which solves a somewhat complicated pde, and its derivatives, for example, the lower left coordinate of $P$ is given by $z^2+\frac12zq-\frac18q_{xx}+\frac38q^2$ where $z$ is a complex parameter.

All I want to do is verify that $P$ and $Q$ solve the following PDE,

$P_x-Q_t+QP-PQ=0$

Given that $q$ satisfies the second PDE.

Any help is greatly appreciated, I have very little experience with mathematica.

Comment: Look up `D`. For further details, we to see the precise definition of `P` and `Q` _in copyable_ Mathematica _code_.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher that's fair, I didn't want to just post my problem with the expectation that others do it. Do you have any tips on how to use the "Assume" function to let Mathematica know $q$ solves a differential equation? thank you for your response. I know how to compute with $D$ if that helps

Comment: Hm. You could try to replace `D[q,x,x]` by minus the rest of the PDE. Then the remaining terms may cancel out.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher ah, that is a nice idea but unfortunately the pde is 5th order in space and all the terms in $P$ and $Q$ are lower order in space. I can add details

Comment: What I meant was something along the lines of `Expand[
 D[P, x] - D[Q, t] + Q.P - 
   P.Q /. {"one term of the PDE for q" -> -"rest of the PDE for q"}
 ]`, where the strings have to be replaced by appropriate expressions.

Comment: For that, is is important that the dependencies of `q` on `x` and `t` are explicit, i.e., you have to write `z^2 + 1/2 z q[x,t] - 1/8 D[q[x,t],x,x] +3/8 q[x,t]^2` and so on.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher ah I see what you mean and it seems like something I could handle. I will give it a shot. Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome. I hope it works out for you.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher It did! Thank you very much. If you would like to create a short answer with your comment I will gladly accept and upvote it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Turning my comments into an answer.*

You could try something along the lines of

```
Expand[ 
 D[P, x] - D[Q, t] + Q.P - P.Q 
 /. 
 {"one term of the PDE for q" -> -"rest of the PDE for q"} 
 ]
```

where the strings have to be replaced by appropriate expressions.

For that, is is important that the dependencies of `q` on `x` and `t` are explicit, i.e., you have to write

`z^2 + 1/2 z q[x,t] - 1/8 D[q[x,t],x,x] +3/8 q[x,t]^2`

and so on.